# Sql query to concatenate 2-3 columns one column is a number and another column is date datatypeusing Ms access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

Ex: if we concatenate 12345 and 31-dec-2019 If we concatenate using & symbol we get 1234531-dec-19 in Ms access but if we do same in excel we get 1234543830 so to get the result as we get in excel what is the query to get this.

Comment: Convert the date to a number. Something like `Field1&Cdbl(DateField)` should work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question, I think it should have more "Details and/or clarity". Please consider the guidelines in the help center [*"How do I ask a good question?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CLng` function to convert the date field to a number:

```sql
SELECT NumberField, DateField, 
[NumberField] & CLng([DateField]) AS CombinedData
FROM Table4;
```